# Custom Post Types Not Showing Up In query_posts Result

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, loop

This query works in some places, but not in others... right now it's not working on the home page. This query is in a file that is included into index.php of my theme.

The regular posts show, but no cutom post types. What's wrong with this query?

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('post', 'video', 'slideshow', 'poll', 'quote'),
  'orderby' => 'date', 
  'order' => 'DESC'
); query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Update: if I remove post from the types... the rest load, but I still need both.

Comment: My own stupidity is to blame... the query was fine, it was the posts per page limit that stopped me from seeing the 'missing posts'. Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

Check that `index.php` is indeed being used, it's *last resort* kind of template when there is no more suitable one.

If you need this in multiple places across the site it might be better to run this in some hook, rather than in template file.

Comment: It is the index that is being used. Even if I use a hook instead, wouldn't the query be the same? Strangely, if I reduce the post_type array to a single class of custom post types that type will display.